# Join a room and automatically rejoin a room when disconnected with socket.io and node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an issue that I imagine has an easy fix but I simply cannot find it. I am connecting a user to my node.js server and rename the socket to the username. I am also adding the user to a room. It all works fine but what happens if the user gets disconnected? I can use the forceNew : true but this will surely only retry to make a new connection not rename the socket and join a room.

I am using server side 'setup' to rename and join room, but how do I automatically do this on reconnect or am I trying to do this the wrong way?

So on my client side I connect like this :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080' ,{'forceNew':true});

var job_id = "100102";
var client_id = "test1";

socket.emit('setup', client_id, job_id);
```

And server side is :

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

 socket.on('setup', (username, job_id) => {
    socket.id = username;
    socket.join(job_id);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I done it this way by adding the 'connection' straight away and it works good. Have to keep the `forceNew:true` as well.

Server side

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit("connection");
 });
```

Client side

```
socket.on('connection', () => {
socket.emit('signin', client_id, job_id);
socket.emit('check', job_id, client_id);
console.log("CONNECTED");
});
```